# Xamarin Forms iOS - Carrier Bar background color changes on Detail, not Master

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a MasterDetail page, Detail is a Naviagtion page, Master contains a Listview.  I'm changing the color of the header bar background color and text using

```
((NavigationPage)Detail).BarBackgroundColor = Color.Navy;
((NavigationPage)Detail).BarTextColor = Color.White;
```

This changes the carrier bar text to white for both the Master and Detail sections, but only changes the carrier bar background on the Detail section, the Master is still white/transparent so the text is no longer visible.  Is this a bug?  I would expect the bar variables to work the same, to only work on the Navigation page since that is the page they are being applied to.

note- I am NOT setting the StatusBarStyle to LightContent, the status bar on a content page shows as black text on a white background.

[image: iOS Carrier Bar]

*Edit - I would expect it to look like this - the CarrierBarText color is changes only on the Navigation Page:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this is expected behavior instead of a bug. The iOS status bar is translucent, but the navigation bar on the Detail page extends to the top of the window so the status bar looks like it has a color.

The Master page also extends to the top of the window so when it's pushed into view, the top 20px get displayed under the status bar, which in this case is just the background of the page. You can change the page's background to Navy to match the navigation bar so it appears more consistent.

Comment: But I did not change the text color of the status bar on the Master Page, or on the entire Master/Detail page.  The code sets both the text color and background color of the Navigation Page which is the Detail page only.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to change the iOS Status Bar Color in Xamarin.Forms is to set the `BarTextColor` of a `NavigationPage`. `Detail` pages must be a `NavigationPage`, so they're able to set the `BarTextColor` property.
Because the `Master` page isn’t a `NavigationPage`, it doesn’t have a `BarTextColor` property, and it can’t change the iOS Status Bar Color.

My recommendation is to change the background color of the `Master` page to a darker color (like Navy Blue) so that the white text in the iOS Status Bar is still visible.

James Montemago did a great blog post that talks about setting the iOS Status Bar Color:
http://motzcod.es/post/110755300272/ios-tip-change-status-bar-icon-text-colors

> If you are using Xamarin.forms you must also set the BarTextColor = Color.White on your NavigationPage! Additionally, you should go into your info.plist and set “View controller-based status bar appearance” to No

Comment: Changing the background color of the Master page does nothing because it does not change the color of the List.  I don't want to change the color of the list.  I'm familiar with James' post and have done everything he recommends but nothing in it addresses this issue.

Comment: I answered another similar question about MasterDetailPage in Xamarin.Forms here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39863909/5953643

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't have anything to do with my question.  I understand fully how MasterDetail pages work, although I will point out that there is no requirement that the Detail page must be a Navigation page - from the documentation "detail page should only be populated with TabbedPage, NavigationPage, and ContentPage instances".  My issue is I am setting the BarTextColor on the NavigationPage ONLY, yet the color is changing on the Master page which is NOT a navigation page.