# Xamarin MasterDetailPage looks ugly

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation-drawer, master-detail

I'm trying to create a MasterDetailPage and I am not quite sure, if I am doing that right, but the drawer / master just looks ugly. For example, the navigation bar color is not showing, ...:
[image: MasterDetailPage]

Any ideas / tips on how to improve it?

Comment: Do you have an image of an example showing what you would like to achieve? I believe the default is a full-height drawer. More examples here: https://material.google.com/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior

Comment: we can't know why is your application ugly and what can be done if we don't know the _code you're using_ and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: For example: The status bar is complete white. How can I achieve, that the status bar has the primary dark color? Or that the whole drawer is below the toolbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## MasterDetailPage Information

Before we jump into the answer, let's go over the `MasterDetailPage` class and how the `MasterDetailPage` is configured in your example.

The `MasterDetailPage` class in Xamarin.Forms requires two `Page` properties:

- `MasterDetailPage.Detail` property needs to be set to a `NavigationPage` containing a `ContentPage` instance.
- `MasterDetailPage.Master` property needs to be set to a `ContentPage` instance

The `Detail` page in your example is on the right side of the screen. The `Detail` page is a `ContentPage` inside of a `NavigationPage` with `NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor` set to `Color.Black`. The `ContentPage` inside of this `NavigationPage` has `ContentPage.BackgroundColor` set to `Color.Grey`.

The `Master` page in your example is on the left side of the screen. It is a `ContentPage` that contains a `ListView`. Without knowing your code, my guess is that the `ContentPage.BackgroundColor` is set to `Color.White` and the the `ListView.BackgroundColor` is not set.

The Navigation Bar is being covered when you select the Navigation Drawer icon. This is happening because the Navigation Bar is on the `Detail` page, and not on the `Master` page.

## Answer To Your Question

### Why is the Navigation Bar Color not showing on the `Master` page?

The `Master` page can only be a `ContentPage` and it can not be inside of a `NavigationPage`, therefore it does not have a Navigation Bar (only a `NavigationPage` can have a Navigation Bar).

### How Can I Improve the UI?

First, verify that you are on the latest version of Xamarin.Forms, v2.3.2.127.

**iOS**

On iOS, you can mimic the `Detail` page's Navigation Bar color by setting the `Padding` property of the `Master` page & setting the `Master` page `BackgroundColor` property to `Color.Black` like so:

```cs
Master = new ContentPage
{
  BackgroundColor = Color.Black,
  Padding = new Thickness(0, Device.OnPlatform(64, 0, 0), 0, 0)
};
```

**Android**

On Android, the expected behavior is to have the `Master` page slide in from the left and cover the `Detail` page. To update the Android UI, I recommend updating one of the three following items: the `Master.BackgroundColor` property, the `ListView.BackgroundColor` property or the color of the icons used in the ListView on the `Master` page.

If you don't want the Navigation Bar to shift right, you can extend `FormsApplicationActivity` in the Android `MainActivity` class, which will prevent the Navigation Bar from moving:

`public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity`

This sample shows that the NavigationBar does not slide over on an Android app when you use `FormsApplicationActivity`:

https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/

[image: Screenshot: Android MasterDetailPage Sample App]

Comment: Using 2.3.2.127, setting `Padding` on the Master `ContentPage` doesn't push the page below the hamburger button, like in your photo -- it still appears on top of everything (including the system status bar). -- It does push the contents down though. -- I believe this is related to [bug #41404](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41404).

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment activity to apply to easily ways of master page in drawerlayout applied to master page and drawerlayout in applied in layout you will dragon customize and action event of common class